# Why are my textures bending on quads?

Tags: texturing, uv, topology

I'm making my first Blender model, a low poly humanoid. After texturing most of it in traditional UV style (just seam + unwrap) I realized drawing on this type of texture is not exactly ideal..

[image: Traditional UVs, wonky perspective]

It's nearly impossible to make things line up across faces, or even in the same face on the far ones, which are warped pretty severely.

So after some research I decided I'd square my UVs like they did in the days where low poly was necessary, given that the ease of drawing straight lines on a texture is cited as one of the biggest benefits. I paid for UV Squares and gave it a whirl, and..

[image: Texture bent into triangles]

The texture is bent in the middle, where the quad is being split into triangles. How Do I remedy this? I've tried `Clean Up > Make Planar Faces`, installing Loop Tools and flattening all my edge loops, moving things vertex by vertex, nothing seems to work. I've seen plenty of low poly models with non-rectangular quads that still use square UVs, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: you probably have 2 solutions, either don't square the UVs, or create loop cuts in order to add topology and remove the triangulation effect?

Comment: Try cube unwrap as your model  seems angular.